# How to calculate process CPU usage in C?

Tags: c, windows, process, cpu-usage

I'm writing a process explorer project.
I can get some Information about processes using Win32 Tool Help Snapshot.
but I can't calculate the amount of CPU usage of each process.
It's a C Window Console Application.

Comment: It is available as a performance counter, Process + % Processor Time.  The api is documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373083%28v=vs.85%29.aspx  Looks to me you are actually using advice given to you in previous questions, you should accept such an answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364801/calculate-cpu-usage-for-a-process , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109345/how-to-gauge-cpu-usage-without-taskmgr , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664257/monitor-cpu-and-memory-consumption-of-a-specific-processes-in-c-windows

Comment: its  duplicate of the following question : 

http://stackoverflow.com/q/1420426/143897

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the ISO C standardized `clock()` function does what you need.

> $ man clock
>
> NAME
>        clock — determine processor time used
>
> LIBRARY
>        Standard C Library (libc, -lc)
>
> SYNOPSIS
>        #include < time.h>
>
> ```
>  clock_t
>  clock(void);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>        The clock() function determines the amount of processor time used since
>        the invocation of the calling process, measured in CLOCKS_PER_SECs of a
>        second.
>
> RETURN VALUES
>        The clock() function returns the amount of time used unless an error
>        occurs, in which case the return value is -1.

You would call it once at the start of main(), save the result and later on compute (clock() - result)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC (beware of rounding for integral division!).

Comment: Maybe the ISO C standardized `clock()` function does what you need.

> DESCRIPTION
>      The clock() function determines the amount of processor time used since
>      the invocation of the calling process, measured in CLOCKS_PER_SECs of a
>      second.
> 

This is per application. If you want global, see /proc/loadavg (under linux). Nothing related to this question.